# As a tourist in the EU, can you order prescription drugs from your home country?

Tags: eu, drugs

I'm a tourist in Belgium. Can I order prescription drugs from Canada (because my prescription drug insurance only covers prescriptions bought in Canada)?

The meds I brought with me were destroyed.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to *order* them and not *bring* them? There are "personal use" exceptions to the import regulations, but those generally assume that you bring the drugs along during entry.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is this about a chronic disease that you suffer or about some unexpected health issue? Who has issued your prescription, a Belgian physician or a Canadian one? In any case prescription drugs are under severe control and importing them from a foreign country is unlikely to be legal, and there is also a possible angle of import tariffs and/or the risk of the parcel being delayed at customs.

Comment: You may find it simpler and not too expensive to pay to see a doctor and get the drugs on a new prescription in Belgium (this very much depends on your condition and the drug of course).

Comment: You appear to have created two different StackExchange accounts. To merge them, see *[How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/)*

Comment: I would imagine the rules on having perscription drugs sent from Canada to Belgium will be dependant on which drugs.

Comment: What kind of drugs?